# How can I set the text of a WPF Hyperlink via data binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, hyperlink

In WPF, I want to create a hyperlink that navigates to the details of an object, and I want the text of the hyperlink to be the name of the object. Right now, I have this:

```
<TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="local:MyCommands.ViewDetails" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Object Name</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
```

But I want "Object Name" to be bound to the actual name of the object. I would like to do something like this:

```
<TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="local:MyCommands.ViewDetails" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/></TextBlock>
```

However, the Hyperlink class does not have a text or content property that is suitable for data binding (that is, a dependency property).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

It looks strange, but it works. We do it in about 20 different places in our app. `Hyperlink` implicitly constructs a `<Run/>` if you put text in its "content", but in .NET 3.5 `<Run/>` won't let you bind to it, so you've got to explicitly use a `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="local:MyCommands.ViewDetails" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

---

**Update**: Note that as of .NET 4.0 the [Run.Text property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run.text?view=netframework-4.8.1) can now be bound:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

Comment: So, does that mean the content property of a Hyperlink is the Inlines collection?

Comment: Is it just me or does this prevent the link from actually working?

Comment: You still need to handle the RequestNavigate

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me in a "Page".

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Path}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Store app (and Windows Phone 8.1 RT app) above example does not work, use HyperlinkButton and bind Content and NavigateUri properties as ususal.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/hyperlinks#create-a-hyperlinkbutton