# Why can't I get my textblock to wrap

Tags: wpf, xaml, word-wrap

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NavModel.NavCommands, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Height="20" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
               <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Command}">
                    <Run Text="really really raelly long string"></Run>
               </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
```

The grid has width and height defined by various * values.

```
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="77*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="92*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I tried this without the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" as well.

How can I achieve my desired effect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that creating custom content inside your <TextBlock> will circumvent TextWrapping. Perhaps you can put the <TextBlock> inside of your <HyperLink>

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense. I wonder if there is a way to get the text to wrap like I need it to in the hyperlink?

Comment: While not exactly your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140996/how-can-i-set-the-text-of-a-wpf-hyperlink-via-data-binding

Comment: Haven't ran into this before, try putting your TextBlock in a Grid of its own to act as container. You could test @kenny's comment by simply putting a MaxWidth on it which should definitely invoke the wrapping. Worse comes to worse, you could just bind the width to something to do the same but still let resize ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel kinda stupid. The solution is to get rid of the Height property on the textblock :(

```
<TextBlock Height="20" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
```

should just be

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
```

and it works.

Comment: This will be something you won't encounter again. :)

Comment: @Loetn nah the height negating wrap thing is something you'll run into again if you work with xaml a lot, it's pretty common.

Comment: @ChrisW. I never ran into this and I work with XAML every day. Maybe I am just lucky. Ooh well, when I encounter this in the future, I will think of this answer. :)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that bites you once, then when someone else has the problem, you find it instantly and they think you are a genius.  Valuable lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.microsoft.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            Navigate To Microsoft Navigate To Microsoft Navigate To MicrosoftNavigate To MicrosoftNavigate To Microsoft
        </TextBlock>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```