# Insert action link into text in WPF Label

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a WPF app i'm working on.

There is a label on my window I use as a status window that I manage with a singleton.

How do i insert a link into that that label?

All the answers I see on this have to do with changing the XAML or the nature of the label.  These solutions don't work, because literally anything can appear in this status window.

I want the link to raise a custom event when clicked.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Example of how the text uploaded to the label should operate.  I need to raise an event when the hypertext formatted word is clicked:

[image]

Comment: [Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140996/how-can-i-set-the-text-of-a-wpf-hyperlink-via-data-binding).

Comment: @Lei Yang, doesn't work.  I don't think any XAML solution will.  I need to insert a single link into text, and post that text to my label.  I'm fairly positive whatever the solution is it will be entirely C#.

Comment: can you upload a screen capture about what your expected result is?

Comment: I added a picture to to the question.  Ignore the line going vertically through the image, its just a guide from the designer.

Comment: that is hyperlink

Comment: _"literally anything can appear in this status window"_ -- really? Like, an actual **cow** could appear there? What does that mean, and why does that preclude changes to the XAML? Your question is too vague and unclear. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows how your scenario works now, and explain _precisely_ what it is you want the code to do. Let other people worry about what's possible and what's not; you are getting ahead of yourself, rejecting solutions before you actually know what a working solution would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inserting a link into text" is the same thing as adding a `Hyperlink` to the `Inlines` collection of a `TextBlock`:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
var hp = new Hyperlink(new Run("error"));
hp.Click += (s, e) => { /* do something */ };
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("There was as an "));
tb.Inlines.Add(hp);
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run(" on run"));
```

This is the one and only way to do this in WPF and it is very simple.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Worked perfectly.